# how to ignore {{ in ansible template module

Tags: ansible, jinja2

below is my ansible playbook:

play.yml

```
- name: gk
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    region_list: ["ap-southeast-1"]
  tasks:
    - name: "Generate region based patching solution  for active regions"
      template:
        #src: "terraform_12/patching/patching.tf.j2"
        src: patching.tf.j2
        dest: "patching_{{ item }}.tf"
      with_items: "{{ region_list }}"
```

below patching.tf.j2

```
{% for region in region_list  %}

provider "aws" {
    alias  = "{{ region }}"
    region = "{{ region }}"
    version = "~> 2.70.0"
    assume_role {
        role_arn     = var.assume_role
        session_name = "terraform"
    }
}




resource "aws_ssm_maintenance_window_task" "lamnbda_execution_after_install_{{ region }}" {
  count            = lower(var.patching_enabled) == "enabled" ? 1 : 0
  name             = "${var.target_infra}-lambda-execute"
  max_concurrency  = 100
  max_errors       = 100
  priority         = 10
  service_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ssm_maintenance_{{ region }}.0.arn
  task_arn         = aws_lambda_function.ssm_patch_export_{{ region }}.0.arn
  task_type        = "LAMBDA"
  window_id        = aws_ssm_maintenance_window.install_window_{{ region }}.0.id

  targets {
    key    = "WindowTargetIds"
    values = aws_ssm_maintenance_window_target.install_target_{{ region }}.*.id
  }

  task_invocation_parameters {
    lambda_parameters {
      payload = "{\"instanceid\":\"{{TARGET_ID}}\"}"
    }
  }
}
```

now from the template, I want to keep the line
`payload = "{\"instanceid\":\"{{TARGET_ID}}\"}"` as it is , without evaluating `{{TARGET_ID}}`

have tried escape characters, like
`payload = "{\"instanceid\":\"'{{'TARGET_ID'}}'\"}"`

and many other combinations, but it somehow shows the `'` along with '{{'
is there any modifications required around that line?

Comment: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#escaping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tthe below syntax can be used to "escape" the curly brackets in jinja templates:

```
{{ '{{' }}TARGET_ID{{ '}}' }}
```

taking part of your j2 template and running it:

j2 template:

```
  task_invocation_parameters {
    lambda_parameters {
      payload = "{\"instanceid\":\"{{ '{{' }}TARGET_ID{{ '}}' }}\"}"
    }
  }
}
```

produced file:

```
  task_invocation_parameters {
    lambda_parameters {
      payload = "{\"instanceid\":\"{{TARGET_ID}}\"}"
    }
  }
}
```